# Ghostscript and high resolutions?

Tags: resolution, ghostscript

I am writing a script that reads some markup data, generates a tex document and converts it to a png image.

As long as I use a resolution up tp 286 px/inch everything works fine. Unfortunately GhostScript, which I use to create picture data, does nothing when I use higher values.

How can I fix this behaviour?

Comment: it would be helpful if you indicated the exact Ghostscript commandline you used to generate your PNG.

Answer (score 4):

Since info about your problem is not very detailed (*What kind of fonts are used in the TeX document? Are they Chinese, Japanese, Korean, or...? Which is the Ghostscript commandline you're using?*) ... here is a thing to check. But it is only a first guess: try to add "`-c "100000000 setvmthreshold" -f /path/to/pdffile.pdf`" to your command:

```
  gswin32c.exe ^
      -o c:/path/to/output.png ^
      -sDEVICE=png ^
      -r600x600 ^
      -c "100000000 setvmthreshold" ^
      -f /path/to/pdffile.pdf
```

This will allow for ~100 MByte extra RAM usage by Ghostscript. If you are on X-Windows (Linux, Unix), then "`-dMaxBitmap=...`" could help (provided you've enough of RAM):

```
  gs \
      -o /path/to/output.png \
      -sDEVICE=png \
      -r600x600 \
      -dMaxBitmap=100000000 \
      -c "100000000 setvmthreshold" \
      -f /path/to/pdffile.pdf
```